# c# detect if the string is long or DateTime before converting

Tags: c#, datetime, type-conversion, long-integer

I have code:

```
if(DateTime.TryParse(objString, out DateTime result))
{
    // ...
}
else if (long.TryParse(objString, out long result))
{
    // ...
} 
else
{
    // ...
}
```

If objString = "782,4" DateTime TryParse is ok and in result I have "782-04-01 00:00:00"

How can i fix this?

Comment: Question is not clear. What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Have you tried to specify the culture info and style?

Comment: If you know in advance the format of the string representation of the DateTime you are expecting, use `DateTime.TryParseExact`. If not, you might want to test if the DateTime is within a valid range.

Comment: Try long first if you dont have simple dates

Comment: Well, what *do* you exect your date to be when providing `"782,4"`? Or do you want `DateTime.TryParse` to return false in this case?

Comment: @HimBromBeere - he probably expected `TryParse` to return false. (Only now see your edit)

Comment: I don't know what datetime format I have,  it depends on culture. I would like see 782,4 not date.

Comment: @Saruman it won't work either, because "782,4" is not a long and will return false in `long.TryParse`

Comment: Use TryParseExact : DateTime.TryParseExact("782,4", "yyyy,M", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out DateTime);

Comment: You could change the order of your `if`s. So, prefer a `double.TryParse` over a `DateTime.TryParse` - FYI `long.TryParse` won't return true with your input string (`782,4`) since `long` isn't a floating-point data type.

Comment: maybe you can try and use `is` keyword, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is

Comment: @styx - a `string` cannot be checked with `is` if it's `DateTime` or `long` - `is` only works if it is `castable` to this type

Comment: Please accept an answer that solves your Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work - if none of the given answer solves your problem - pls explain why it doesn't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to just simply change the order you are checking your string.

So instead of:

```
if(DateTime.TryParse(objString, out DateTime result))
{
    // ...
}
else if (long.TryParse(objString, out long result))
{
    // ...
} 
else
{
    // ...
}
```

Just simply, change the order of your `if` statements:

```
if (long.TryParse(objString, out long result))
{
    // ...
}
else if (DateTime.TryParse(objString, out DateTime result))
{
    // ...
} 
else
{
    // ...
}
```

As I said in my comment already, you have to use `double.TryParse` if you want to evaluate floating-point numbers

So maybe use this, instead:

```
if (double.TryParse(objString, out double dblResult))
{
    // ...
}
else if (DateTime.TryParse(objString, out DateTime dateTimeResult))
{
    // ...
} 
else
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the culture:

```
DateTime.TryParse(objString, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out result)
```

Comment: The same result.